# asp.net core with Azure AD authentication - handle user assignment required setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1 web application which uses Azure AD to authenticate users. The application has recently had the 'user assignment required' option set within AAD so that only certain users are authenticated to use the application. This works correctly though I am now looking to make the user experience better for users that have an account in AzureAD but have not been assigned to the application. Issues I have:

- For user that has not been assigned, the OnRemoteFailure event is hit. I can potentially parse the failure message and look for text like 'The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application' and direct the user to an appropriate error page. Is this the best way to handle this? I cannot see any other data I can tap into to distinguish this type of response?
- Some users will have two Azure AD accounts and it is possible that one is assigned to the application and another is not. In the case that they sign in to the Azure account that does not have access to the application, they will be stuck with each click of Login taking them straight back to the website and the Unauthenticated page. Ideally the user needs to be given the chance to login using their other AD Account rather than having to clear their browser cookies to reset things. I'm not sure how I would go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, I have found that adding:

`options.Prompt = "select_account";`

to

`services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>`

has done the trick and is allowing the user to switch account